# Android - Navigation drawer with custom list item layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using Mike Penz's Material Design Navigation Drawer [library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). I want to use my custom layout for list item of navigation drawer. I could not find in documentation. So my question is how to use custom layout for navigation drawer item?

Comment: You can post a issue at github itself and you would get a reply from mike itself.

Comment: Thank you, Raghunandan. I will do it

Comment: @JoeRichard edit the row item layouts from the library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the library as dependency to your build.gradle, download the library from Github and edit `material_drawer_item_secondary.xml` or `material_drawer_item_primary.xml` inside layout folder, and add it to your project as library replacing the earlier one or the dependency in build.gradle. This way you can customise the navigation items.

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me the steps, how to add as library after editing the xml? I am new to android studio. When I searched, there were so many ways to add library to a project in android studio, and its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a much simpler solution to achieving custom drawer items, is to create your own CustomDrawerItem class (wherein you can specify the Layout resource of your drawer item). This has the added benefit of giving you additional control grammatically that rebuilding the source code and manipulating the raw XML will not.

Here is a simple Custom drawer item class in 8 lines of code

```
public class MyCustomDrawerItem extends AbstractBadgeableDrawerItem<MyCustomDrawerItem>
{
    @Override
    public int getType() { return R.id.material_drawer_badge_container; }

    @Override
    @LayoutRes
    public int getLayoutRes() { return R.layout.lyt_item_my_custom_drawer_item; }
}
```

As you can note from the example above, the two methods you want to override are `getType()` and `getLayoutRes()` with `getLayoutRes()` where you specify your own custom drawer item resource.